# Can I pipe text from an external source into a questoin, based on a response to a previous questoin?

Tags: qualtrics

[sorry about the title- can't use the word 'question']

I'm trying to take the response from a previous question and use it to look up a matched value in an external data set, then display the matched value as piped text in a following question.

For instance, if question 1 has choices (A, B, C, and D), 
and my data set contains (A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4), 
can I pipe the number into question 2, based on the letter selected in question one?

I have a rough idea about how I could do this by adding some javascript but I'd like to stick to the native Qualtrics features if possible. Can this be done using embedded data or contact lists in Qualtrics?

Answer (score 0):

Your simple example could be done by manually including the data set in to qualtrics survey flow as branches.

You could also do this by recoding the values of each answer and piping in selected choices recode value.

Alternatively you could create a webservice to receive your answer and return the corresponding number.

Comment: Hi Anthony! Thanks for the suggestions. 

I simplified the example to make the question a little more clear but there are 17 different choices, and the corresponding 'number' that it would match to is actually a string of a few hundred characters. 

Branching is a possibility but a bit tedious with 17 different options. I'm not sure if the recode option would work with a string that long. What I really need is a switch / case statement, so I may have to go with JS.

Comment: In my opinion doing it in js would be just as tedious as setting up branches with an embedded data variable meant to hold the codes. Recoding won't work with a high character number so it looks like you are down to a few options.